# How to prevent OData service call on model change

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a sap.m.Table whose "items" are bound to oData v2 model. I need to delete item on click on delete icon. Here is what I do: 
On click of delete icon, I get all the rows in the model, delete the one in question and set the property of model again. 
However since the model is changed, it triggers a backend round trip and brings the latest data and table shows the original rows again.

I tried setting binding mode to OneTime but that does not work. Also tried setting RefreshAfterChange to false but even then service was called again.

Here is my code -

Controller

```
onInit: function() {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("url", {
        json: true,
        useBatch : false,
        refreshAfterChange: false,
        defaultBindingMode: "OneTime"
    });

    this.getView.().setModel(oModel, "model1");
},

onDeleteIconPress : function(oEvent) {
    // get the selected row
    // get all the rows in oOriginalRows
    // loop over oOriginalRows and delete the selected row from it

    // set the model to reformed oOriginalRows
    this.getView().getModel("omodel1").setProperty("/", oOriginalRows);
   // Till this point every thing looks fine. I can see changes in the model
    // refresh is called automatically and data service triggers backend call
    // This fetches original data again and table shows all data again
}
```

How can I not trigger the round trip again? I need to update the locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Odata is server side model, it always triggered a round trip. So I did not bind my sap.m.Table to Data model. Instead I triggered a read manually. On success I copied the data received to local JSON model. I bound my table items to this JSON model. Now the delete button works just fine.

```
// Define a JSON Model
oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

//oModel is Odata model defined in manifest file
oModel.read("/entity1", {
    success: function(oData, oResponse){
        oJsonModel.setProperty("/entity1", oData.results);

        // bind oJsonModel to table here
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work with a ODataModel as it is strictly server side.  Please use the corresponding [remove](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#remove) method to delete an entity from the server.

Comment: There is nothing to delete in the backend. The odata service does a join on several tables and returns data. I had figured it out that it is server side model, so I tried setting default operation mode to "Client". It did not work. From the documentation I understand that it is experimental and works for sorting and filtering only at the moment. I am trying one possible way to achieve what I want. If that works I will post solution here

Comment: Why do you delete then, if there is nothing to delete?! Does not make sense.

Comment: Well the case is that, what should be displayed in dashboard is governed by say Table1. Based  on entries maintained in Table1 joins are done on several tables and that's the data Odata service "A" returns. On delete button I need to remove entry from model so that it is no longer shown UI. Meanwhile another Odata delete service "B" is triggered to remove entry from Table1. However this change in model also triggers read again for Data service "A". I found a solution for this. See my answer.